# Symbol 'subscribe' could not be resolved

Tags: ros, subscribe

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I am trying to subscribe to a topic, namely nav_msgs::Odometry.
subodom = nh_.subscribe<nav_msgs::Odometry> ("RosAria/pose", 1,  &SensorSonar::callback, this);
Strangely I get this error message:
**Description   Resource    Path    Location    Type
Symbol 'subscribe' could not be resolved libSENSOR.h    /mmrprojekt/src line 79 Semantic Error**

Just one line bellow I subscurbe to another Topic without any problem.
sub = nh_.subscribe <sensor_msgs::PointCloud>  ("/RosAria/sonar",1, &SensorSonar::callback, this);

Any ideas?

BR

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/49319/symbol-%27subscribe%27-could-not-be-resolved/) by [Eisenhorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/3282/eisenhorn/) on ROS Answers with karma: 82 on 2012-11-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You are using the same callback for both subscribes. I would guess, that the parameter only fits one of those, so that the signature of the templated method does not match the given callback.

---

Originally posted by [Ben_S](https://answers.ros.org/users/1072/ben_s/) with karma: 2510 on 2012-11-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Eisenhorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/3282/eisenhorn/) on 2012-11-29**:
Arg yes I changed it shortly after writing this question. I was too blind :-) Thanks!

**Comment by [Ben_S](https://answers.ros.org/users/1072/ben_s/) on 2012-11-29**:
Glad you solved it. Such errors are really annoying... :) Could you please accept my answer, so that its obvious, that the question is finished? Thanks!

**Comment by [Eisenhorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/3282/eisenhorn/) on 2012-12-05**:
Ops sorry. I clicked the green checkbox to the left. Is that all I have to do? :-)

**Comment by [Ben_S](https://answers.ros.org/users/1072/ben_s/) on 2012-12-05**:
Yes, thats it. :) Thanks